# How to listen continuously to a socket for data in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I open a socket which sends and receives data on a socket.
I have the following code shown below to open a socket and then send information.

```
# Socket Information
host = "localhost"
port = 6800

# Initailize the socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, port))
```

```
# Method to send the data on the socket
# This method is called periodically every 5 seconds to send the data

def send_data():
    sock.send((request_string).encode("utf-8"))
```

The issue that I am currently facing. I want to be able to continuously `listen` for data and I am unsure on how to do it. I dont want to be blocking the other parts of my code as I am listening on the port. Do I need to do the listen on another thread? Is it just a simple `while(1)` loop which listens on the same port `6800`.

Any help for the implementation of the listen method would be appreciated.

Comment: use `thread` with `while True:` loop. It will be simpler.

Comment: @furas Could you please provide me a sample code on how to do this? I would appreciate it alot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example which use `Thread` to handle client so `listen()` can wait for another client. It is popular solution and you should see it in some tutorials for `Python` or even for `C`.

**server.py**

```
import struct
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time

# --- constants ---

HOST = ''   # local address IP (not external address IP)

            # '0.0.0.0' or '' - conection on all NICs (Network Interface Card),
            # '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost' - local conection only (can't connect from remote computer)
            # 'Local_IP' - connection only on one NIC which has this IP

PORT = 8000 # local port (not external port)

# --- functions ---

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    #request_string = data.decode("utf-8")
    try:
        while True:
            conn.send(data)
            #conn.send(request_string.encode("utf-8"))
            time.sleep(5)
    except BrokenPipeError:
        print('[DEBUG] addr:', addr, 'Connection closed by client?')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[DEBUG] addr:', addr, 'Exception:', ex, )
    finally:
        conn.close()

# --- main ---

#all_threads = []         

try:
    # --- create socket ---

    print('[DEBUG] create socket')    

    #s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s = socket.socket() # default value is (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) so you don't have to use it

    # --- options ---

    # solution for "[Error 89] Address already in use". Use before bind()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    # --- assign socket to local IP (local NIC) ---

    print('[DEBUG] bind:', (HOST, PORT))

    s.bind((HOST, PORT)) # one tuple (HOST, PORT), not two arguments

    # --- set size of queue ---

    print('[DEBUG] listen')

    s.listen(1) # number of clients waiting in queue for "accept".
                # If queue is full then client can't connect.

    while True:
        # --- accept client ---

        # accept client and create new socket `conn` (with different port) for this client only
        # and server will can use `s` to accept other clients (if you will use threading)

        print('[DEBUG] accept ... waiting')

        conn, addr = s.accept() # socket, address

        print('[DEBUG] addr:', addr)

        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        t.start()

        #all_threads.append(t)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print(ex)
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
finally:
    # --- close socket ---

    print('[DEBUG] close socket')

    s.close()

    #for t in all_threads:
    #    t.running = False # it would need to build own class Thread
    #    t.join()
```

And now you can run client's code many times at the same time and all of them will get data from server.

**client.py**

```
import struct
import socket
import sys

# --- constants ---

HOST = ''   # (local or external) address IP of remote server
PORT = 8000 # (local or external) port of remote server

try:
    # --- create socket ---

    print('[DEBUG] create socket')

    #s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s = socket.socket() # default: socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM

    # --- connect to server ---

    print('[DEBUG] connect:', (HOST, PORT))

    s.connect((HOST, PORT)) # one tuple (HOST, PORT), not two arguments

    # --- send data ---

    print('[DEBUG] send')

    text = 'Hello World of Sockets in Python'
    print('[DEBUG] text:', text)

    # convert text to bytes

    data = text.encode('utf-8')
    print('[DEBUG] data:', data)

    # get data length

    length = len(data)
    print('[DEBUG] length:', length)

    # convert `length` int to 4 bytes

    #length = struct.pack('!i', length)
    print('[DEBUG] length as 4 bytes:', length)

    # send `length` as 4 bytes

    #s.send(length)

    # send data as bytes

    s.send(data)

    while True:
        print(s.recv(1024))

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print(ex)
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
finally:
    # --- close socket ---

    print('[DEBUG] close socket')

    s.close()
```

---

There are so many comments because I took example code from my GitHub and add `Thread`: [furas/python-examples/socket/simple-protocol](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket/simple-protocol)

---

**EDIT:** Client uses thread to run `while` loop with `send()` and at the same time it runs `while` loop with `recv()` in main loop.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time

# --- constants ---

HOST = ''
PORT = 8000

# --- functions ---

def sender(s):
    print('sender')  

    while True:
        s.send(data)
        print('send:', data)
        print('--- sleep ---')
        time.sleep(3)

# --- main ---

data = b''

try:
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    text = 'Hello World of Sockets in Python'
    data = text.encode('utf-8')

    threading.Thread(target=sender, args=(s,)).start()

    print('receiver')  
    while True:
        temp = s.recv(1024)
        if temp:
            data = temp
            print('recv:', data)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print(ex)
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
finally:
    print('[DEBUG] close socket')
    s.close()
```

Server which use `thread` to handle client.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import time
import datetime

# --- constants ---

HOST = ''   
PORT = 8000

# --- functions ---

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    try:

        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print('recv:', data)

            data = str(datetime.datetime.now()).encode()
            conn.send(data)
            print('send:', data)

            print('--- sleep ---')

            time.sleep(1)

    except BrokenPipeError:
        print('[DEBUG] addr:', addr, 'Connection closed by client?')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[DEBUG] addr:', addr, 'Exception:', ex, )
    finally:
        conn.close()

# --- main ---

try:
    print('[DEBUG] create socket')    
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print('[DEBUG] bind:', (HOST, PORT))
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print('[DEBUG] listen')
    s.listen(1)

    while True:
        print('[DEBUG] accept ... waiting')
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('[DEBUG] addr:', addr)
        t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        t.start()

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
    print(ex)
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
finally:
    print('[DEBUG] close socket')
    s.close()
```

Comment: I was looking for something where I could do the ```sock.recv(2048)``` while listening on that port in like a while true statement. I wanted to assign the sock.recv(2048) in a global buffer so it could be used in the other functions. I dont think your answer reflects this. May you please help me. I dont see the ```thread``` as well.

Comment: you can't `recv()` from socket which you `listen()` and this is why `accept()` creates new socket with new port for client.

Comment: BTW: code shows you how to use Thread so you can use it in your way.

Comment: if you don't use `listen()` but only `recv()` and `send()` then remove `listen()`, `accept()` and it may still be useful example - you run thread to use `send()` in `while`-loop and at the same time you use `recv()` with `while` loop in main thread. Threads use the same memory so they can share data.

Comment: I added `client` which use `thread` to run `while` loop with `send()` and at the same time it runs `while` loop with `recv()` in main loop.